# Use Jackson Filter for an ObjectMapper to screen out null fields?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there some way to use a Jackson filter to screen out null fields? I know there are annotations, but I don't always want to screen out null fields. I only want to do it in some cases. Is there a way to define a filter to avoid serializing null fields that I can register with an ObjectMapper? Or is there some other way I can do this?

Comment: what are the cases you are taking about? Special types, annotated elements, or object instances with certain values?

Comment: I am testing a RESTful API and the requests/responses are in JSON format. When there are edit actions on existing objects, not all fields will be changed. The JSON representation of HTTP request that edits the object will contain nothing for those fields. When the POJO representing the edited fields is instantiated, those fields which are not changing will be null in the POJO. I don't want those nulls to be serialized into JSON underneath the hood. I just want those fields to be filtered out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the class you want ignore nulls in with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` or you can configure your `ObjectMapper` to do it for every class with `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);`

While you could probably do it with a filter, you'd end up with tons of conditional logic to maintain. If you don't want to annotate your classes you can do the same thing with MixIns.

You can also implement a per-class custom serializer to handle your specific use case if neither of the above works for you. Simply implement `JsonSerializer` or `StdSerializer` for the classes in question and annotate your target class with `@JsonSerialize(using = MyClassSerializer.class)`

Comment: I don't want to ignore nulls globally, at all times. I just want to ignore a null field under specific circumstances. I want a filter to ignore one field when it is null under limited conditions.

Comment: Understood, I've added to my answer to cover that case.

Comment: I think Mix-Ins and/or a customer serializer is the way to go. Therefore, I'm accepting your answer. There are simply too many if clauses to use a filter.